# python send mail with Cc :

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm trying to add Cc: to my email script with Python language.
Here's my code :

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


email = "my addr"
password = "password"
send_to_email = "destination"
cc = "cc mail"
subject = "hello"
message = "hello"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = email
msg["To"] = send_to_email
msg["Cc"] = cc
msg["Subject"] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

i have this error : smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO2P265CA0009.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')

Can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: what is the isssue?

Comment: Thanks for posting a [mcve]. We need a bit more information. What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: Sorry for that, i actualy have an error : smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO2P265CA0009.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')

Comment: i just want to send a specific mail to Mr1 and in Cc : Mr 2 from my email without being logged before